# How do I restore a jailbroken iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

How do I restore to the normal non jailbroken state my jailbroken iphone 3G? Is there any permanent change when you jailbreak it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is plug your iPhone into iTunes, click on it under Devices:

[image: Devices>iPhone]

And click "Restore":

[image: Click restore in iTunes]

iTunes will make sure that you do *actually* want to restore:

[image: Are you sure you want to restore?]

Jailbreaking does not make any permanent changes; a restore will put your iPhone back exactly the way it was before you jailbroke it.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any permanent changes made to your iPhone when JailBreaking. All you need to do is plug it into your computer, open up iTunes, and update/restore iOS normally. This will return it to a fully working, non-jailbroken state.